# I am getting extra white space in webview. How to remove that in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using `webview` in my application for getting question and options. I am getting extra white space at bottom of the question. For long length questions,it is working fine and short length questions some extra white space is occuring at bottom.
I have tried this code and modified **all padding properties to 0dp**

```
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

enter code here
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:paddingRight="0dp"
 android:paddingBottom="0dp"
 android:paddingTop="0dp"
 android:paddingLeft="0dp">                             

 <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

How to remove this spaces.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot

Comment: post your xml please

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/c1_cnxlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

WebView cannot calculate it's height correctly **always** if you set it's **"layout_height"** to **"wrap_content"**

You should use **"match_parent"** or a specific value like **"150dp"**

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```